# Is it (in)secure to give the ApplicationPoolIdentity write access to a folder inside your web application folder?

Tags: security, iis, applicationpoolidentity

Recently we implemented a feature which dynamically generates a LESS file in our App_Themes folder. This is done on application start.

This requires us to give the @ApplicationPoolIdentity@ write access to the App_Themes folder.

Our system administrator, however, does not want us to give the @ApplicationPoolIdentity@ that write access. For security reasons.

Is it insecure to do that? What are the security risks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there were any remote code execution vulnerabilities in your application, or within ASP.NET or IIS itself, anyone compromising your system through your application or web server will likely get a command shell, and be logged in as e.g. `DefaultAppPool` on your server.

If there is write access to a folder, then the attacker could write to this folder themselves.

For example, they could host their own content on your site at `example.com/App_Themes/index.html`, or they could upload an exploit that allowed priveledge escalation to that of administrator. In the latter case they would probably need executable permissions too, unless they could in someway make the webserver execute it, for example by requesting the URL of the dropped exploit.

Of course, the vulnerability has to be there in the first place for this to happen. Preventing write access too can be viewed as "defence in depth", however if this is needed by your application then it may be an acceptable risk. An alternative is to find another way to implement your desired functionality.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. In the end we found a different way to implement what we needed. It just took a while to make it working and I wasn't sure if it was worth to do it.